# Data type that restricts symbols?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database

I was asked a day ago by a fellow developer if I know a data type that restricts symbols, thus, only accepting alphanumeric values. As far as I know, there can't be one. But then again, I don't know everything so I took the time to ask.

If there is one, either in MSSQL or MySQL, please enlighten me. It may come in handy in the future.

Cheers!

Comment: I don't think so, according to the mysql documentation, but if i were you , if i wanted an only alphanumeric field, you can do it in the Coding Part.

Answer (score 1):

A datatype cannot restrict the acceptable characters. However, a `CONSTRAINT` can be used to do the same. For example, in SQL Server, you can add a constraint on a particular column to check if data being inserted meets a criteria.

```
create table tbl(textcol varchar(10))

alter table tbl add constraint cs_chk_chars check (textcol not like '%[^A-Za-z0-9]%')
```

The above constraint will cause an insert to fail if it contains non-alphanumeric characters.

Ideally, however, you would do this validation at the application level to ensure only valid data is sent to the DB in the first place.

Comment: Remark to MySQL: It permits the use of a check clause but ignores it currently (5.7.x).